# Как реализовать 2 каталога на Virtuemart

Tags: joomla

Всем привет.

Проблема такова: Есть авто-магазин на Виртумарте, нужно сделать каталог оригинальных запчастей, и не оригинальных. Вывести эти два пункта в меню. На главной категории, их трогать нельзя.

При клике на пункт оригинальных запчастей, открывался список марок машин - модель - запчасть.

Можно сделать два сайта... но, может есть проще вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Проще на главной выводить какие-то особенные категории(вплоть до собственного модуля), а ветвление вмарта сделать человеческим: корень-(не)оригинальные-марка-модель-запчасть.

Это избавит вас от многих проблем в будущем. Хотя если желание поизвращаться велико - можете

1. Поставить две джумлы с 2 вмартами соответственно
2. Создать тип товара "Оригинальный" и "Неоригинальный" - это как бы "правильный" вариант, т.е. по идее ваша задача решается именно так. Но... мягко говоря, работа с типами реализована в virtuemart не лучшим образом. Добавление типа товара к детали - 2-4 перезагрузки страницы, заполнение нескольких полей и много кликов. Вы офигеете с *этим* работать (не вы - так манагеры).
3. Сложный, прогерско-хакерский способ - найти где включаются конфиги (файл вроде virtuemart.cfg.php называется, могу соврать) и перехватывать их чем-то вроде `if (JRequest::getVar('Itemid') == $nonoriginalid) { require 'c1.php'; } else { require 'c2.php'; }`. Т.о. включать файлы с, например, разными префиксами таблиц. Так же придется поступить с админкой.

В любом случае мне кажется, вам лучше использовать совет №0 - он наименее затратный во всех планах.

Comment: Да, где то читал, про то что можно раздвоить БД на одном магазине, но это геморойно, за магазом смотреть буду не я, заказчик, а он точно офигеет.

Ладно, спасибо за ответ!